# Filebot won't work as it depends on JavaFX, but it is installed

Tags: apt, java

I'm trying to install [Filebot](http://www.filebot.net/) 4.7.9 on a fresh install of 17.04 Ubuntu GNOME, however, I get the following error when I start the application:

> Failed to initialize JavaFX. Please install JavaFX.

JavaFX is installed:

```
apt list --installed | grep openjfx
```

> WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.
>
> libopenjfx-java/zesty,zesty,now 8u111-b14-1 all [installed,automatic]
>
> libopenjfx-jni/zesty,now 8u111-b14-1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
>
> openjfx/zesty,now 8u111-b14-1 amd64 [installed]

I've tried to remove and reinstall a couple of times with no luck.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and how to get this working?

Comment: Potentially a known (but not yet fixed) bug in Filebot: https://www.filebot.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=4900